# Как добавить запись через WPF в базу данных SSMS

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, ssms

Как добавить запись в базу данных через WPF? Вывожу всю таблицу через SqlQuery.

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Odb.db = new System.Data.Entity.DbContext(connectionString);
        phonesGrid.ItemsSource = Odb.db.Database.SqlQuery<Phone>("SELECT * FROM phonesTable", new SqlParameter("@param1", "1")).ToList();
    }
```

Пробовал аналогичным способом добавить записи через запрос INSERT, но ничего не происходит.

```
private void saveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Odb.db.Database.SqlQuery<Phone>($"INSERT INTO phonesTable (Title, Company, Price) VALUES (Test, Test, 20");
    }
```

Comment: Используйте EF правильно. EF это когда вы не пишете запросы в большинстве случаев, оперируя простыми классами. Условно `context.MyDataBase.Add(new MyItem("Вася", 55)); context.SaveChanges();`.

Comment: у вас insert инструкция вроде невалидная, вы руками её пробовали выполнить в SSMS?

Comment: SSMS - это **не** база данных. Ваша база данных - Sql Server.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал добавление через SqlCommand.

```
private void saveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
       
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO phonesTable (Title, Company, Price) VALUES (@namePhone, @company, @price)", conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@namePhone", "Test");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@company", "Test");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", 20);

            conn.Open();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Остановитесь на чём-то одном: либо чистый ADO.NET, либо Entity Framework.